# How to trigger a pop callback function after the app is restored and the second route is popped?

Tags: flutter, dart, navigator, flutter-navigation, flutter-go-router

The issue is I do not have the value yet when the app gets killed. Imagine such a scenario:

1. User is on route `A`.
2. User navigates to route `B` (route stack is now `[A, B]`)
3. User moves the app into the background
4. System kills the app due to battery saving measures or whatever
5. User re-enters the app (expects to land on the previously visited route)
6. The app restores the desired route stack (`[A, B]`).
7. The user selects an item and pops back to route `A`.

Example code:

```dart
// Step 1: User navigates to RouteB
final result = await GoRouter.of(context).push('RouteB'); // Step 2: User pops back and the returned value is stored to `result`
print(result); // Step 3: Doesn't get triggered
```

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: [ i didn't find any way to save route-stack but u can get it done by replacing routes as only go-forward replacing routes ] 1. use PushReplacement to navigate between routes. 2. save the latest route on the local-storage.  3. when u come back to the app then fetch the latest-route from local-storage & navigate to that route & to navigate by using PushReplacement as before.

Comment: I know how to save a route-stack, but not how to trigger the pop callback function that is being awaited for on the previous page.